# Addition of new columns using forloop in spark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe which is created dynamically.There are also a list of columns which needs to be selected from the dataframe.

I need to iterate through the list of columns needed and check for the existence of those columns in dataframe. If found then the dataframe column needs to be renamed else if not found create the new column and place it with 'null' value.

I have tried with using forloop and then if condition as below:

My dataframe has columns : a.col1,a.col2,a.col3,a.col4,b.col2

```
val cols_needed = "a.col1,a.col2,a.col3,a.col4,b.col1,b.col2".split(",")
for(c <- cols_needed)
{
  if(Try(df(c)).isFailure)
  {
    df.withColumn(c, lit(null))
  }
  else
  {
    df.withColumn(`c`,df(c))
  }
}
```

I need to use this dataframe after the loop for further operations.

Also tried using for loop with yield, but its is giving me an array of dataframes.

How do I update this dataframe inside forloop and if conditions.
Because when I try to printSchema outside the forloop it has the old schema and not the updated one.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The API is immutable so `withColumn` does not mutate the existing val `df` but return a new one. For example

```
val newDf = cols_needed.foldLeft(df) {
  case (tmpdf, c) =>
    if (Try(df(c)).isFailure) {
      tmpdf.withColumn(c, lit(null))
    } else {
      tmpdf.withColumn(`c`, df(c))
    }
}
// now newDf contains the added columns
```

Comment: This solution worked like charm.Was trying a lot with different alternatives but in vain.Thanks a lot for the timely help.

Comment: I found a post might be helpful to explain spark forloop performance, fyi https://medium.com/@david.mudrauskas/looping-over-spark-an-antipattern-e10ac54824a0

Comment: These topics are not related, in this post the loop is only in driver when building the DAG